# Qt c++ How to change MAC Address?

Tags: windows, macos, qt, dns, ip

I'm in Windows 10 and Qt Creator 4.8.2, Based on Qt 5.12.2. I want to change mac address but I don't no how. Also the ip address, gateway and dns.
Thanks

Comment: Before asking a new question check if it has already been asked. This one seem to have already an extended discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627728/change-mac-address-by-adapter-description . The code is C, but i guess it can work in C++

Comment: Try this, but I don't work in Qt, at least not like that, you have to modify some things, which didn't work for me.
Ask if anyone had it done in Qt directly.
Greetings and thanks for answering.

Comment: **1)** What have you tried so far? (this is not a code-writing service) **2)** "you have to modify some things, which didn't work for me" ... you might want to elaborate what exactly does not work for you - we can't read your mind, ya know

Answer (score 0):

Here you have how to change MAC address, ips and dns. Qt creator 4.8.2 Based on Qt 5.12.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)

.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include<QProcess>
#include<QSettings>
#include<QString>
#include<QDebug>
#include<QFile>
#include<QVariant>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void restartNetwork();
    void setNetEnabled (bool isEnabled);
    void runCMD (QString cmdlst);

    void configNet(QString ip1, QString ip2, QString ip3, QString ip4, QString gateway, QString dns1, QString dns2);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSettings settings(R"(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001)", QSettings::NativeFormat);

    settings.setValue("NetworkAddress", "AABBCCDDEEFF");

    qDebug() << settings.value("NetworkAddress");

    configNet("10.10.0.10", "192.168.0.242", "192.168.10.200", "10.20.0.30", "10.10.0.1", "190.190.223.225", "190.190.223.235");

    restartNetwork();
}

void MainWindow::restartNetwork()
{
    setNetEnabled (false);
    setNetEnabled (true);
}

void MainWindow::setNetEnabled(bool isEnabled)
{
    QString cmdlst;

    if(isEnabled)
    {
        cmdlst = "netsh interface set interface Ethernet ENABLED";
    }
    else
    {
        cmdlst = "netsh interface set interface Ethernet DISABLED";
    }

    runCMD(cmdlst);
}

void MainWindow::configNet(QString ip1, QString ip2, QString ip3, QString ip4, QString gateway, QString dns1, QString dns2)
{
    QString ip1CMD, ip2CMD, ip3CMD, ip4CMD, dns1CMD, dns2CMD;

    if(ip1!="")
    {
        ip1CMD = QString("netsh interface ip set address Ethernet static %1 255.255.255.0 %2").arg(ip1).arg(gateway);
        runCMD(ip1CMD);
    }

    if(ip2!="")
    {
        ip2CMD = QString("netsh interface ip add address Ethernet %1 255.255.255.0").arg(ip2);
        runCMD(ip2CMD);
    }

    if(ip3!="")
    {
        ip3CMD = QString("netsh interface ip add address Ethernet %1 255.255.255.0").arg(ip3);
        runCMD(ip3CMD);
    }

    if(ip4!="")
    {
        ip4CMD = QString("netsh interface ip add address Ethernet %1 255.255.255.0").arg(ip4);
        runCMD(ip4CMD);
    }

    if(dns1!="")
    {
        dns1CMD = QString("netsh interface ip add dns Ethernet %1").arg(dns1);
        runCMD(dns1CMD);
    }

    if(dns1!="")
    {
        dns2CMD = QString("netsh interface ip add dns Ethernet %1").arg(dns2);
        runCMD(dns2CMD);
    }
}

void MainWindow::runCMD(QString cmdlst)
{
    QProcess process;

    process.start(cmdlst);

    qDebug ()<<cmdlst;

    process.waitForStarted();
    process.waitForFinished();

    qDebug()<<QString::fromLocal8Bit(process.readAllStandardOutput());
}
```

I Hope it can help!!!